# Global options for python-click MultiCommand

Tags: python, python-click

I'm implementing a classical CLI toolbox with python and I selected [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/) as my argument parser. Adding a command should just be adding a file. From there the command is listed in the help and so on. This part is working through a click [MultiCommand](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/commands/#custom-multi-commands).

What I didn't achieve yet are global options like `loglevel` or `configfile`. I don't want every command to deal with the options. I think most global options create somewhat global state. How do achieve this, I'm  lost.
I also think that this something that could very well be covered by the official documentation.

```py
# __init__.py
import pathlib
import click
import os
import typing


class ToolboxCLI(click.MultiCommand):
    commands_folder = pathlib.Path.joinpath(
        pathlib.Path(__file__).parent, "commands"
    ).resolve()

    def list_commands(self, ctx: click.Context) -> typing.List[str]:
        rv = []
        for filename in os.listdir(self.commands_folder):
            if filename.endswith(".py") and not filename.startswith("__init__"):
                rv.append(filename[:-3])
        rv.sort()
        return rv

    def get_command(
        self, ctx: click.Context, cmd_name: str
    ) -> typing.Optional[click.Command]:
        ns = {}
        fn = pathlib.Path.joinpath(self.commands_folder, cmd_name + ".py")
        with open(fn) as f:
            code = compile(f.read(), fn, "exec")
            eval(code, ns, ns)
        return ns["cli"]

@click.group(cls=ToolboxCLI)
@click.option("--loglevel")
def cli(loglevel):
    "Toolbox CLI "


# commands/admin.py
import click


@click.group() # <- how do i get global options for this command?
def cli():
    pass


@cli.command()
def invite():
    pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*click_example.py*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import pathlib
import typing

import click


class ToolboxCLI(click.MultiCommand):
    commands_folder = pathlib.Path.joinpath(
        pathlib.Path(__file__).parent, "commands"
    ).resolve()

    def list_commands(self, ctx: click.Context) -> typing.List[str]:
        rv = []
        for filename in os.listdir(self.commands_folder):
            if filename.endswith(".py") and not filename.startswith("__init__"):
                rv.append(filename[:-3])
        rv.sort()
        return rv

    def get_command(
        self, ctx: click.Context, cmd_name: str
    ) -> typing.Optional[click.Command]:
        ns = {}
        fn = pathlib.Path.joinpath(self.commands_folder, cmd_name + ".py")
        with open(fn) as f:
            code = compile(f.read(), fn, "exec")
            eval(code, ns, ns)
        return ns["cli"]


@click.group(
    cls=ToolboxCLI,
    context_settings={
        # Step 1: Add allow_interspersed_args to context settings defaults
        "allow_interspersed_args": True,
    },
)
@click.option("--log-level")
def cli(log_level):
    "Toolbox CLI"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

Above: Add [`allow_interspersed_args`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/api/#click.Context.allow_interspersed_args) so `--log-level` can be accessed anywhere

Note: I renamed `--loglevel` -> `--log-level`

In *commands/admin_cli.py*:

```py
import click


@click.group()  # <- how do i get global options for this command?
@click.pass_context  # Step 2: Add @click.pass_context decorator for context
def cli(ctx):
    # Step 3: ctx.parent to access root scope
    print(ctx.parent.params.get("log_level"))
    pass


@cli.command()
@click.pass_context
def invite(ctx):
    pass
```

Use [`@click.pass_context`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/api/#click.pass_context) and [`Context.parent`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/api/#click.Context.parent) to fetch the params of the root scope.

Setup: `chmod +x ./click_example.py`

Output:

```
❯ ./click_example.py admin_cli invite --log-level DEBUG
DEBUG
```

P.S. I am using something similar to this pattern in a project of mine ([vcspull](https://github.com/vcs-python/vcspull/)), see [vcspull/cli/](https://github.com/vcs-python/vcspull/tree/v1.12.2/vcspull/cli). Inside of it I pass the log level param to a [`setup_logger(log=None, level='INFO')`](https://github.com/vcs-python/vcspull/blob/v1.12.2/vcspull/log.py#L27-L50) function. This source is MIT licensed so you / anyone is free to use it as an example.

Comment: Thanks @Tony N , your answer and your example are really helpful. I didn't notice before that `__init__.py:cli` _AND_ `commands/admin.py:cli` are called.
It even works without setting  `allow_interspersed_args=True` - the generated help texts then don't tell you about the global options though.